# Check if a string slice is contained in HashSet<Rc<String>> without allocating a new String

Tags: rust, smart-pointers, hashset, borrowing

I'm caching words coming from the input in a `HashSet<Rc<String>>`.
Can I somehow use `&str` as a key for this set when checking if it contained in set as I could for `HashSet<String>`?

Using a `HashSet<String>`, it works:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::collections::HashSet;

let input = "";
let string = input.to_string();
let rc_string: Rc<String> = Rc::new(string.clone());

let set: HashSet<String> = [string.clone()].iter().cloned().collect();
assert!(set.contains(&string));
assert!(set.contains(input));
```

But if I try to use a `HashSet<Rc<String>>`:

```
let string_cache: HashSet<Rc<String>> = [rc_string.clone()].iter().cloned().collect();
assert!(string_cache.contains(&rc_string));
assert!(string_cache.contains(&string));
assert!(string_cache.contains(input));
```

Then I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::rc::Rc<std::string::String>: std::borrow::Borrow<str>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:16:26
   |
16 |     assert!(string_cache.contains(input));
   |                          ^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::borrow::Borrow<str>` is not implemented for `std::rc::Rc<std::string::String>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <std::rc::Rc<T> as std::borrow::Borrow<T>>
```

Comment: Are you sure you need the items to be `Rc<String>`? There may be a simpler solution if your underlying requirement could admit a different data structure.

Comment: Justified uses of `Rc<String>` are not unheard of, but rare, since you can't mutate it. Consider `Rc<str>` instead, which has less indirection and does implement `Borrow<str>`

Comment: @trentcl thanks, `Rc<str>` could be the solution. The only downside I've found, in the current implementation of `Rc::from(input_string)` input_string memory is not reused https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1845-shared-from-slice.md#vec-and-box

Comment: Yep, that's a drawback. Ultimately it comes down to whether an extra copy at creation time, or an extra indirection every time you access it, is more costly. (Note too the extra copy can sometimes be avoided; turning a `&str` into an `Rc<str>` can be done in one step without creating an intermediate `String`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message says, `HashSet::contains` requires that the type of the item stored in the collection has a `Borrow` implementation for its argument type. There is no implementation of `Borrow<str>` for `Rc<String>`.

You can't add this implementation yourself because neither the types involved nor the trait are from your crate. However, you can create a newtype wrapper for `Rc<String>` and implement whichever `Borrow` implementations you might need:

```
#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Hash)]
struct CacheItem(Rc<String>);

impl Borrow<str> for CacheItem {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &str {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl Borrow<String> for CacheItem {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &String {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl Borrow<Rc<String>> for CacheItem {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Rc<String> {
        &self.0
    }
}

let string_cache: HashSet<CacheItem> = [rc_string.clone()].iter().cloned().map(CacheItem).collect();
assert!(string_cache.contains(&rc_string));
assert!(string_cache.contains(&string));
assert!(string_cache.contains(input));
```

Newtype wrappers constructed like this should have zero runtime cost. However, you may need to add a number of extra trait implementations in order to use it conveniently.